# How to get rid of HTML tags after submitting TinyMCE text in react

Tags: reactjs

This is my react code.

```
import React, { useState, useRef } from "react";
import { Editor } from '@tinymce/tinymce-react';
const PostBlog = () => {
const editorRef = useRef(null);
const [description, setDescription] = useState("");
    const log = () => {
        if (editorRef.current) {
            setDescription(editorRef.current.getContent());
            console.log(description);
        }
    };
return(
<div className="tinymce">
                    <Editor
                        apiKey="kwoypty9nsvg3at4nannkt6kla0ab2e0tp9wtux0f9u6oqpu"
                        onInit={(evt, editor) => editorRef.current = editor}
                        initialValue="<p>This is the initial content of the editor.</p>"
                        init={{
                            forced_root_block:false,
                            selector:"textarea",
                            height: 200,
                            width: 740,
                            menubar: false,
                            toolbar: "bottom",
                            plugins: [
                                'advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor',
                                'searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen',
                                'insertdatetime media table paste code help wordcount'
                            ],
                            toolbar: 'undo redo | formatselect | ' +
                                'bold italic backcolor | alignleft aligncenter ' +
                                'alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | ' +
                                'removeformat | help',
                            content_style: 'body { font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; font-size:14px }'
                        }}
                    />
                    <button type="button" onClick={log}>Log editor content</button>
                </div>
)
```

When I click on 'Log editor content' I get the output with HTML tags. As the initial value of TinyMCE editor is '

This is the initial content of the editor.

', The output I get is the same with HTML tags, but I want the output as text without HTML tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this cleanup function to remove the HTML tags from a string

```js
const cleanup = (input) => {
  const div = document.createElement('div');
  div.innerHTML = input;
  return div.innerText;
};
```